# Запятая перед И: "Она знала, что мне нужны деньги и мне подойдет любая работа"

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены, придаточное-предложение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед И.

> Она знала, что мне нужны деньги и мне подойдет любая работа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая не нужна: придаточные однородные,союз И одиночный. Но повтор местоимения *мне* лучше убрать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!